# If else not working with empty variables/Data in PHP

Tags: php, rest, if-statement

I am working wiht RestApi in php and i want to check whether "Post Data" is empty or not with one condition but right now my "else" part is working instead of "if",Where i am wrong ? Here is my code

```
$email = $this->input->post('otpEmail');
$one = $this->input->post('one');
$two= trim($this->input->post('two'));
$three= trim($this->input->post('three'));
$four= trim($this->input->post('four'));

if(empty($email) && empty($one) && empty($two) && empty($three) && empty($four)) {
    $responseJSON = array("Status" => false, "Message" => "Please enter your otpEmail,one,two,three,four");
    header("content-type:application/json");
    $response = json_encode($responseJSON);
    echo $response;

}
else
{
    $responseJSON = array("Status" => true, "Message" => "All data exist here");
    header("content-type:application/json");
    $response = json_encode($responseJSON);
    echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Your `if` statement only runs if *all* the fields are empty. Use `||` if you want to report an error if *any* of them are empty.

Comment: you should say what you expected with that code and what happened instead. so far its not clear what "not working" means. The code merely does what you expressed with it. If the expression is wrong, you should explain in your how words what you think the code does so that it is easy to spot the error.

Comment: @harkre: i want if All parameters (email,codeBox1,codeBox2,codeBox3,codeBox4) are empty/not passing as parameter then if part should work ( validation error message should display) But if pass All parameters then "Else" part should work, Simple!

Comment: Perhaps you mean you want if anyone of them is empty, which _could_ be all of them but could be only one (or up to all). You perhaps should consider to work with `null` values so you could check this with `isset()` which accepts multiple variables - and not only one as `empty()` does. But that is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as your code seems logically incorrect ( replace && with || )

```
if(empty($email) && empty($codeBox1) && empty($codeBox2) && empty($codeBox3) && empty($codeBox4)) {

}else{

}
```